# amsbook + titleps breaks \tableofcontents

Tags: table-of-contents, amsbook, titleps

### Issue

If I use `titleps` with `amsbook` class, then the `\tableofcontents` does not work properly. The following error is produced:

```
./mwe.tex:11: Missing control sequence inserted.
<inserted text> 
                \inaccessible 
l.11 \tableofcontents
```

The `titleps` manual seems to be aware of the possible conflict between `titleps` and AMS classes. But I am not sure what is causing the problem with `\tableofcontents`.

### Additional Info

Here's a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage{titleps}
\title{MWE}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Test}
Hello!
\end{document}
```

I've used

- pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020)
- amsbook 2020/05/29 v2.20.6

I've also noticed that there is `[` that is added to the title of the table-of-contents page as below:

[image]

Comment: The package `titleps` and the class `amsbook` are not compatible, as far as I know.

Comment: It actually stops compiling with a ‘Missing control sequence inserted <inserted text> \inaccessible’ error message. However, loading `titlesec` with option `[pagestyles]` compiles fine.